# Fair Coin Flips

Tags: combinatorics

> Michele flips a fair coin nonstop. Two students, Thomas and George,
>   decide to 
>   make a bet about whose sequence of flips will occur first from the moment they 
>   begin observing the results of Michele's flips. Thomas picks the sequence 'HTT'.
>   Find, with proof, a sequence George can pick that gives him an edge over Thomas
>   in their bet.

I set up a diagram for the different cases and used it to compute the probabilities of all of the cases.

The sequence we pick has to be of length $3$. Otherwise, this question is trivial.

Comment: After Michele first flips a head, after the next flip, you'll be looking at HH or HT. Think about what happens in each case.

Comment: I think that for this question to make sense, each player has to pick a sequence of length 3. Ozera, if this is what you meant, please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: If George could pick the sequence H, or T, or HT, he would always win. If one wants to sucker Thomas into playing the game, the rules should allow the poor guy to win *sometimes*.

Comment: Can somebody give an explanation why my naive view is wrong that the following tosses are independent from the already seen HTT? Is the higher occurence of the T event meaning that it shows up less in subsequent tosses to balance out over the long run into $50:50$ T and H events?

Comment: This game is called Penny Ante.  James Grime to the rescue : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcYnlSenF04

Comment: @DanielV : Thanks for the name. Looking it up shows a [nice page](http://plus.maths.org/content/os/issue55/features/nishiyama/index), where an amazing Conway's algorithm is explained!

Comment: Thanks DanielV and gar for those references!

Answer (score 1):

First, let us see the expected number of tosses required for each sequence of three:

\begin{align*}
  \begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
    \mathrm{HHH}, \mathrm{TTT} & 14\\
    \mathrm{HHT}, \mathrm{THH},  \mathrm{TTH}, \mathrm{HTT}  & 8\\
    \mathrm{HTH}, \mathrm{THT} & 10 \\ \hline
  \end{array}
\end{align*}

Since $\mathrm{HTT}$ was chosen, let's pick $\mathrm{HHT}$ to compare the probability of getting one before the other.

We can use the following absorbing markov chain to find that:

\begin{align*}
  \left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
 & \mathrm{I} & \mathrm{H} & \mathrm{T} & \mathrm{HT} & \mathrm{HH} & \mathrm{HTT} & \mathrm{HHT}\\\\
\mathrm{I} & 0 & \dfrac{1}{2} & \dfrac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\\
\mathrm{H} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dfrac{1}{2} & \dfrac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\\\
\mathrm{T} & 0 & \dfrac{1}{2} & \dfrac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\\
\mathrm{HT} & 0 & \dfrac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dfrac{1}{2} & 0 \\\\
\mathrm{HH} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dfrac{1}{2} & 0 & \dfrac{1}{2} \\\\
\mathrm{HTT} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\\\
\mathrm{HHT} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
\end{align*}

'I' is the initial state.

From the matrix, we find the probability of absorption from non-absorbing states to be:

\begin{align*}
  \left(\begin{array}{rr}
\dfrac{1}{3} & \dfrac{2}{3} \\\\
\dfrac{1}{3} & \dfrac{2}{3} \\\\
\dfrac{1}{3} & \dfrac{2}{3} \\\\
\dfrac{2}{3} & \dfrac{1}{3} \\\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
\end{align*}

Hence, we see that from the initial state, the probability of getting $\mathrm{HHT}$ first is $\dfrac{2}{3}$

Also, see  IV. 6.3. p. 271 in Analytic Combinatorics, which has an example about patterns.

### Update

We can calculate the probabilities by solving the following set of equations, after tossing one head:

\begin{align*}
  p_h &= \frac{1}{2}\left(p_{hh}+p_{ht}\right) \\
  p_{hh} &= \frac{1}{2}\left(p_{hh}+p_{hht}\right) \\
  p_{ht} &= \frac{1}{2}\left(p_{h}+p_{htt}\right) \\
  p_{hht} &= 0 \\
  p_{htt} &= 1
\end{align*}
which gives the probability of ${\rm HTT}$ occuring first, and is same as calculated from the markov chain.

If we solve the above equations by taking $p_{htt}=0$ and $p_{hht}=1$, we get the probability of ${\rm HHT}$ occuring first.

Comment: Can you explain to me why $\mbox{HHH}$ needs $14$ tosses to show up? Or how I should interpret $\mbox{HHH}$ and $14$?

Comment: If you can show work without using a Markov Chain, that would be great. Right now I am just case bashing and am getting  $HHT$ as well. I do not think Markov Chains would look like a friendly solution.

Comment: @mvw : They are the average number of tosses required for the pattern to appear. They can be obtained building some recurrences, or a markov chain. I am sure they have already been discussed in some other questions. We can also find it in the reference I have mentioned.

Comment: @Ozera : Okay, will see. I and Markov chain became friends just recently. Anyway, it's easy to see why HHT is more likely to occur without calculating anything: After we get H, both HH and HT are equally likely. From HH and HT, the absorbing states are just a step away. But, if we get H, the state HH remains; the state HT will go back one state to H.

Answer (score 0):

I would say for example HHH

If Michele has flipped ...,**H,H,H**,... then you have the following possible sequences:

We look at a sequences with 5 tosses and containing HHH:

HHHHH (3), HHHHT (2),HHHTT (1),HHHTH (1) ,THHHT (1),HTHHH (1), THHHH (2), HHHHT (2) ,TTHHH (1)

If you look at HHHH there are 3 possible sequences of HHH which can be exctract. You have to sum the numbers in the brackets.
Thomas:

If Michele has flipped ...,**H,T,T**,... then you have the following possible sequences:

HTTHH,HTTTH,HTTHT,HTTHH,HHTTH,HHTTT,THTTT,THTTH,HHTTH, HHHTT,HTHTT,THHTT;TTHTT

It is only a suggestion.

greetings,

calculus

Edit: The point is, if George take HHH, than there is a probability, that Michele flips H next. And from HHHH there is a greater possibility for George to select HHH, than the probabilty, that Thomas select HTT from HTTH OR HTTT.